Well definedness of the operator $T/U$
Here is the question I am thinking about:
Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional, $T \in \mathcal{L}(V),$ and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ invariant under $T.$ The quotient operator $T/U \in \mathcal{L}(V/U),$ is defined by $$(T/U)(v + U) = Tv + U$$ for each $v \in V.$
$(a)$ Show that the definition of $T/U$ makes sense (which requires using the condition that $U$ is invariant under $T$) and show that $T/U$ is an operator on $V/U.$
My thoughts:
1- For showing that it is well defined, I need to show that its definition does not depend on the representative $v$ which means that I want to show that if $Tv + U = Tw + U$ then $(T/U)(v + U) = (T/U)(w + U).$ I am not sure where and when to use the condition that $U$ is invariant under $T.$
Could anyone clarify this to me please?
2- For showing that $T/U$ is an operator on $V/U,$ since an operator on $T/U$ means a linear map from $T/U$ to $T/U.$ Then we have to show that $T/U$ is a linear map. Here is my attempt: For every $v,w \in V$ and $\lambda \in F,$ we have
$$1- (T/U)( (v + w) + U) = T(v + w) + U = (Tv + Tw) + U = (Tv + U) + (Tw + U) = (T/U)( v + U) +  (T/U)( w + U) $$
$$2- (T/U)( (\lambda v) + U) = T( \lambda v) + U = \lambda Tv + U = \lambda (Tv + U) = \lambda (T/U)( v + U)  $$
Is my proof for being an operator is correct or I missing any more steps or details?

Hint for Part $1$:  $v+U=w+U \iff v-w \in U$.

@RobertShore thank you very much for the hint. What about part (2) question?

I think part $(2)$ is fine.

Actually, you have the implication backwards for part $1$.  You need to show that if $v+U=w+U$, then $Tv+U=Tw+U$.  In English, this means that no matter what “name” (i.e., coset representative) you choose for a particular coset of $U$, you end up with the same result after applying $T/U$.
But $v+U=w+U \iff v-w \in U$, which in turn implies $T(v-w) \in U$.  (This is where you use that $U$ is invariant under $T$.)  And $T(v-w) \in U \Rightarrow Tv-Tw \in U \Rightarrow Tv+U=Tw+U,$ which is what you needed to prove.
Your proof of Part $2$ looks fine.
